# Android view dismiss when scroll down

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am working on an Android app, in which an Activity contains a header view and a ListView below it.

I want when the listview scrolls down, the header dismiss (at the same speed I scroll), and when the listview scrolls up, the header shows back.

I am not sure if I explained it clearly. If I did not make it clear, please take a look at the Twitter Android app. The action bar tab has the same effect as I described.

Thank you!

Comment: So have you implemented any code for this?

Comment: @PiyushGupta Yeah I have a standard header view and a listview now, but have no idea how to approach this. Pointers will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you please post some code ?

Comment: Is [Fading ActionBar](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/05/fading-actionbar/) what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi @Haresh I don't think posting my code helps in this case because there's not any implementation about this effect yet... Just standard `RelativeLayout` Contains a `RelativeLayout` and a `ListView`

Comment: @AndrewT. Hi Thanks, but not really. I am talking about a fade view, not action bar (though the example is action bar)

Comment: hi @AllanJiang you can try my solution...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need `pinnedHeaderListView` for that you need implement logic of below two library or you can use these library to desire effect that you want.

https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView

https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/